# lost connection to mysql server during query after about 1000 seconds

Tags: mysql, docker, timeout

I'm trying to alter a table with large data. And everytime I send the alter query, it failed after about 1000 seconds(not exact).

I've read related posts about this issue(there were many) and I modified mysql server variables, such as wait_timeout, following the instructions. Actually, it had been 600 seconds that my query lasted until I modified a variable(I don't remenber which one) which had been 600. I set it to a very big number, then it started to failed after 1000 seconds.

Now I'm trying to find the variable whose value is 1000, but I can't. I'm using latest mysql docker image and didn't change any setting but some timeout variables.

Is this really the problem of mysql server variable? How can I unlimit the query execution time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query as follows:

SELECT MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000 * FROM table;

UPDATE: You should use max_execution_time instead.

SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000)*/ * FROM table;
MAX_STATEMENT_TIME was renamed to max_execution_time in MySQL 5.7.8.

Comment: It was set to 0. I think it means unlimited.

Comment: I set it to 999999999 but it failed 1000 seconds after again.

Comment: Which Version of mysql you use ?

Comment: 5.7.17. But I can see MAX_EXECUTION_TIME instead of MAX_STATEMENT_TIME

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. That variable was available for each session. I'm trying again.

Comment: I'm waiting 1000 seconds now. But as I said before, maybe 0 mean unlimited, so...

Comment: It didn't work. I think there is the other varaible.

Comment: delayed_queue_size
gtid_executed_compression_period
innodb_old_blocks_time
group_concat_max_len
innodb_lru_scan_depth
key_cache_block_size
max_digest_length
max_length_for_sort_data
max_sort_length
metadata_locks_cache_size
performance_schema_max_digest_length
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length
These are all variables around 1000(1000 or 1024). And I can't find any one.